# Can't fetch data from local API React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I have a web application, in react using an API made in Laravel. I want to make a mobile app using the same API. I can't fetch data, because I get the error:

> NETWORK REQUEST FAILED.

This is how I try to fetch data:

```
handleButton = () => {
    try {
        fetch(`127.0.0.1:8081/test`).then(response =>
        console.log(response)
    );
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };
```

I tried changing the IP in dev settings to my machine id, i tried using localhost not the IP (127.0.0.1) but none of those fixed it... I can't seem to find anything else. Here is the error text:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Network request failed
TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (blob:http://localhost:8081/cfc373de-8318-4df3-b46a-7b17d4926c5e:42556:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (blob:http://localhost:8081/cfc373de-8318-4df3-b46a-7b17d4926c5e:47998:27)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (blob:http://localhost:8081/cfc373de-8318-4df3-b46a-7b17d4926c5e:46859:20)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (blob:http://localhost:8081/cfc373de-8318-4df3-b46a-7b17d4926c5e:46686:16)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/cfc373de-8318-4df3-b46a-7b17d4926c5e:46796:47
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (blob:http://localhost:8081/cfc373de-8318-4df3-b46a-7b17d4926c5e:16875:37)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (blob:http://localhost:8081/cfc373de-8318-4df3-b46a-7b17d4926c5e:16488:44)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/cfc373de-8318-4df3-b46a-7b17d4926c5e:16245:17
    at MessageQueue.__guard (blob:http://localhost:8081/cfc373de-8318-4df3-b46a-7b17d4926c5e:16442:13)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (blob:http://localhost:8081/cfc373de-8318-4df3-b46a-7b17d4926c5e:16244:14)
```

***EDIT:***

I am using Android Studio's emulator, because I don't have an Android device running Android > 5.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IP of your machine on the local network.

Open up terminal/cmd.

If you're using a mac, you can use `ifconfig` and it's usually under `en0`. You will see something like `192.168.0.32` or similar.

If you're using windows, you can use `ipconfig`.